# autobahn not working with tomcat 7 websocket

Tags: android, websocket, tomcat7, autobahn

Sorry for my english.

I want to program a native app in Android to connect with a server for interactive comunications. Websocket tegnology is perfect fothis. I have installed and working Tomcat 7.0.39 in my laptop with IP 192.168.1.250. I have tryed the examples echo, snake, etc and it works fine using ws://localhost:8080/.... and using ws://192.168.1.250:8080/...

I'm using autobahn with eclipse to connect to my server. I have installed apk in my Android mobile with autobahn client websocket sample and it connects perfectly withn ws://echo.websocket.org.

The problem is that from android to my server (in my laptop) not work. From android to ws://echo.websocket.org works fine (I supose that autobahn example works well), my server works fine because de examples comes with tomcat work fine.

Because I have to make intesive work with information that travel between server and clients, I can't use javascript on server side, I need java servlets or others to work with databases, files ando so on.

What is wrong? Firewall is off, and wireshark show me how android client try to connect to my laptop server ( I don't anderstand wireshark info well ) but the connection loses.

This my android code:

```
    package com.example.autobahnandroiddemo;

    import de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection;
    import de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketException;
    import de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketHandler;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       static final String TAG = "de.tavendo.autobahn.echo";
       private static final String PREFS_NAME = "AutobahnAndroidEcho";

       static EditText mHostname;
       static EditText mPort;
       static TextView mStatusline;
       static Button mStart;

       static EditText mMessage;
       static Button mSendMessage;

       private SharedPreferences mSettings;

       private void alert(String message) {
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
          toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
          toast.show();
       }

       private void loadPrefs() {

          mHostname.setText(mSettings.getString("hostname", ""));
          mPort.setText(mSettings.getString("port", "9000"));
       }

       private void savePrefs() {

          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
          editor.putString("hostname", mHostname.getText().toString());
          editor.putString("port", mPort.getText().toString());
          editor.commit();
       }

       private void setButtonConnect() {
          mHostname.setEnabled(true);
          mPort.setEnabled(true);
          mStart.setText("Connect");
          mStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                start();
             }
          });
       }

       private void setButtonDisconnect() {
          mHostname.setEnabled(false);
          mPort.setEnabled(false);
          mStart.setText("Disconnect");
          mStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnection.disconnect();
             }
          });
       }

       private final WebSocketConnection  mConnection = new WebSocketConnection();

       private void start() {

          final String wsuri = mHostname.getText() + ":" + mPort.getText();

          mStatusline.setText("Status: Connecting to " + wsuri + " ..");

          setButtonDisconnect();

          try {
             mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onOpen() {
                   mStatusline.setText("Status: Connected to " + wsuri);
                   savePrefs();
                   mSendMessage.setEnabled(true);
                   mMessage.setEnabled(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextMessage(String payload) {
                   alert("Got echo: " + payload);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
                   alert("Connection lost.");
                   mStatusline.setText("Status: Ready.");
                   setButtonConnect();
                   mSendMessage.setEnabled(false);
                   mMessage.setEnabled(false);
                }
             });
          } catch (WebSocketException e) {

             Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
          }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          mHostname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hostname);
          mPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
          mStatusline = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusline);
          mStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
          mMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);
          mSendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMsg);

          mSettings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
          loadPrefs();

          setButtonConnect();
          mSendMessage.setEnabled(false);
          mMessage.setEnabled(false);

          mSendMessage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnection.sendTextMessage(mMessage.getText().toString());
             }
          });
       }

       @Override
       protected void onDestroy() {
           super.onDestroy();
           if (mConnection.isConnected()) {
              mConnection.disconnect();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case R.id.quit:
                finish();
                break;
             default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
          return true;
       }

    }
```

AND THIS IS MY SERVLET TOMCAT CODE:

```
    package servlets;

    import org.apache.catalina.websocket.MessageInbound;
    import org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound;
    import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet;
    import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.CharBuffer;

    public class SimpleWebSocketServlet extends WebSocketServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String string, HttpServletRequest hsr) {
            return new MessageInbound() {

                @Override
                protected void onBinaryMessage(ByteBuffer bb) throws IOException {

                }

                @Override
                protected void onTextMessage(CharBuffer cb) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println(cb.toString());
                    WsOutbound outbound = getWsOutbound();
                    outbound.writeTextMessage(cb);
                }
            };
        }

    }
```

I don't know what's wrong. Have another solution to use android client in conjuntion with server (java servlets on similar tecnology) through websockets?
Thanks

Comment: Could you post the AutobahnAndroid and/or Tomcat log output?

Comment: I have the exact same problem when using Tomcat (works fine with jetty though..)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have put the code of connecting into onCreate.